# SOQL query not returning rows that do exist on visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, soql

SOQL query not returning rows on visualforce page that do exist in object I am having issues retrieving records which exist from an object via a SOQL query on a visualforce page

How do I know they exist? I have used force explorer and workbench and the following returns a record

```
SELECT Code__c FROM External_membership_label__c WHERE Code__c = '3'
```

OK, so the visualforce page does not return the record above, with the code below (few lines from code)

```
  public String gvlLCCODE {get;set;}

  if(gvlLCCODE != null || gvlLCCODE != ''){

        List<External_membership_label__c> exisitingGVLcodes = [SELECT Code__c FROM External_membership_label__c WHERE Code__c = :gvlLCCODE];

        if (exisitingGVLcodes.Size() > 0){
            //blahh blahh
        }
}
```

Any suggestions? I have debug telling me 'gvlLCCODE' has a value that exists in the object. Also, if I change the SOQL to say, for example, return the current user from the users table, it returns a record and then enters the IF statement.

I think its a security issue I have missed. But I have also checked these.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

well, for one, in your IF statement you probably want to use &&, instead of ||.

Are you having the problem with the test method?  if so, then it's because that method doesn't have access to the existing records by default.

Comment: nothing to do with the test method, just the SOQL querying the object. The test method is not doing a system assert against this bit of code yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should listen to Kirill about the &&, both condtions should be met, not just one. Likewise, the `||` is meaningless, formula `(a!=b)|(a!=c)` is always true for any `a` when `b!=c` as is the case here

Second, it sounds as you definitely have a security issue here. To verify change extension's declaration from `with sharing` to `without sharing` and run. If you get the row you have sharing security issues with the row.

Comment: Yep its definitely a security issue, Just need to know what I've missed, The Administrator has done his checks, might be one for salesforce support. || && have been modified, silly mistake.

Comment: check the object sharing setup, if its not public, add "Sharing button" to the page layout, open the row in question in GUI and click on Sharing. This will give you the list of all people/groups that have access to it and through what source.

Comment: Or your users' profiles do not have access to taht obejct, but if you said your admin checked that as you say, then this should be the first thing he checked.